# SpringBoot 3.2- BaseStateMachineListener (eventNotAccepted in log instead of LifecycleObjectSupport )

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

We recently upgraded springBoot version to 3.2, and Java 21 64 bit.
We observed the LifecycleObjectSupport object log was output every time an Event was notified in Spring StateMachine:

`2023/12/20,13:48:06.600 INFO [DeviceBroker ] [nio-8080-exec-7] mework.statemachine.support.LifecycleObjectSupport : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@7efa3f63 2023/12/20,13:48:06.600 INFO [DeviceBroker ] [nio-8080-exec-7] mework.statemachine.support.LifecycleObjectSupport : stopped ATTACHED / / uuid=da1c1d7d-7d54-4484-bf49-d224f7324a3e / id=null`

Currently it says eventNotAccepted in BaseStateMachine:

`WARN [DeviceBroker ] [nio-8080-exec-7] .device.base.statemachine.BaseStateMachineListener : [eventNotAccepted] Device- Cat event not accepted: GenericMessage [payload=CONNECT, headers={id=351edf7d-8504-39dc-29cd-973600fdba5a, timestamp=1708581146172}]`

This is warning message in the log also LifecycleObjectSupport object is not there now.
We want to know why is that happening and its impact .
is it expected in current version ?

Comment: Anyone have any Idea on this ? One relevant issue I found in gitHub : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/132